# phoca download error not found

Tags: php, html, wordpress, joomla

I'm trying to design a new site with Joomla 2.5.6 (french translation installed), Phoca download 3.2.1 and Gallery Tree 3.1.2
I've created so far one empty category for all 2012 categories, but each time I'm clicking on the 2012 item in the module, I'm getting the following error message : 
Not Found

The requested URL /component/phocadownload/category/3-2012 was not found on this server.

The goal is to have only subcategories in this category (and one for each year). but I've tried to add images to that category without any success.

I've not planned to create a menu and manually create a link to these emply categories. If the category contains a sub-category, this subcategory is working like a charm (correctly displayed, etc...)

The link given by the module is /component/phocadownload/category/3-2012 instead of /index.php/component/phocadownload/category/3-2012. The index.html is missing.

Have-I done something wrong in my setup ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: 2.5.19 or 3.2.3: you simply cannot use an old version or your site will be hacked  - quickly!

Try adding a letter at the beginning of the alias text: I am guessing phoca is getting confused by the number-only alias, so use something like `y2012` as an alias, your url will look like `/3-y2012` which should be acceptable.